# CALS table border line missing in PDF view (XSLT)

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsl-fo

This is my Sample CALS table XML structure.

```
<table id="table_Test" frame="none">
  <tgroup cols="7">
    <colspec colname="cgen1"/>
    <colspec colname="c1" colwidth="10*"/>
    <colspec colname="c2" colwidth="10*"/>
    <colspec colname="c3" colwidth="10*"/>
    <colspec colname="c4" colwidth="10*"/>
    <colspec colname="c5" colwidth="10*"/>
    <colspec colname="cgen2"/>
    <thead>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry colsep="0"/>
        <entry colsep="0"/>
        <entry colsep="0"/>
        <entry colsep="0"/>
        <entry colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="1" morerows="0"/>
        <entry align="center"><para>Test1</para></entry>
        <entry align="center"><para>Test2</para></entry>
        <entry align="center"><para>Test3</para></entry>
        <entry align="center"><para>Test4></entry>
        <entry align="center"><para>Test5</para></entry>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
        <entry>
          <para> Test6</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>Test 7</entry>
        <entry>
          <para>Test 8</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <para>Test 9</para>
        </entry>
        <entry>
          <para>Test 10</para>
        </entry>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0" morerows="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0"/>
        <entry><para>Test 11</para></entry>
        <entry><para>Test 12</para></entry>
        <entry><para>Test 13</para></entry>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0" morerows="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0"/>
        <entry><para>Test 14</para></entry>
        <entry/>
        <entry/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0" morerows="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0"/>
        <entry><para>Test 15</para></entry>
        <entry/>
        <entry/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
      <row>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0" morerows="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0"/>
        <entry rowsep="0" colsep="0" morerows="0"/>
      </row>
    </tbody>
  </tgroup>
</table>
```

but border line are missing in PDF view . how to handle the "rowsep", "colsep" variable in XSLT . I have set frame value is none . 
[image]

but I need output like this [image]

I am new for xslt writing . please help me how to archive my requirements use XSLT . How can I solve this?

Comment: Your question seems to miss details about how you transform your XML. All I see is some input XML in a particular format. Can you please add all your input, code, how you invoke it and your outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify that you want a border, in this case on each `<entry>`:

```
fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"
```

[FO tables](http://w3schools.sinsixx.com/xslfo/xslfo_tables.asp.htm) and [border styles](http://www.datypic.com/sc/fo11/a-border-1.html)

For the @colsep and @rowsep attributes you have to make the borders conditional:

```
<fo:table-cell>
<xsl:if test="not(@colsep='0')">
    <xsl:attribute name="border-left">1pt solid black</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="border-right">1pt solid black</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

Comment: How to implement @rowsep/@colsep attribute in CALS table?

Comment: I've added that. FO works a bit differently, so you have to 'translate' colsep/rowsep to the borders attributes.

Comment: If the questioner implements the XSL-FO stylesheet, it is better to consult original CALS table specification (https://www.oasis-open.org/specs/tablemodels.php). For instance if entry/@colsep!=”0”, the right side border should be displayed but it is ignored in the last column. Also if entry/@rowsep!=”0”, the bottom side border should be displayed but it is ignored in the last row.

Comment: I have been facing other issues same xml. "thead/row/entry" is borderline not working... but "tbody/row/entry" is border left, right working good. Can you please help me. How to solve the issues

Comment: Can you add the table transformations from your XSLT to the question? Without those it's impossible to see where things are going wrong.